# Create a semicircle in scene kit

Tags: swift, scenekit

Is it possible to create a semicircle in scene kit? I thought I might be able to do it with scntorus and maybe delete half of the segments, but there is no indication that this is possible.

Answer (score 2):

Use SCNShape, and a Bezier path that is a semicircle.